# Saying bismillah when breaking fast

Tags: sawm, iftar

Is it mandatory to say bismillah before breaking the fast in Ramadan? I usually just say a small dua (allahumma laka sumtu wa bika aamantu wa`ala rizq-ika aftartu) before I do, is this permissible?

Answer (score 2):

Saying "Bismillah بسم الله " is not mandatory, but among the sunan of eating.
This is based on:

> "When one of you eats food, then let him say: 'Bismillah.' If he forgets in the beginning, then let him say: 'Bismillah Fi Awwalihi Wa Akhirih (In the Name of Allah in its beginning and its end.)"
> ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1858))

It is also permissible to say the full basmalah:

> Bismiallah ar-Rahmani ar-Raheem
> بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

Having this said this ruling applies at any meal not necessarily nor exclusively for iftar in Ramadan.

Further there's hardly a n authentic du'a for breaking the fast as you may read in:
[What Duaa is to be recited before breaking the fast and at the beginning of the fast?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31490/what-duaa-is-to-be-recited-before-breaking-the-fast-and-at-the-beginning-of-the)

Comment: thank you also where i live there isnt an azaan so i just check the suhoor and iftar times on different websites. They all have different times so i pick the earliest one for suhoor and latest one for iftar, is this correct

Comment: @zasad2306 this is a different question. You should first check which calculation method suits your location most. For this I suggest you ro check questions with the tag prayer-timing. What you are doing might be the safest, but it is rather makrooh the sunnah is to delay suhoor until before fajr and start iftar as soon as posdible

Comment: I checked every website they all say they’re the most accurate but they have different timings so i don't know

Comment: @zasad2306 I said check this website all of them are accurate for the region they are designed for. You can't use Umm al-Qura or ISNA method in Europe for example.

Comment: there’s a website with a mosque 6 minutes away from me would it be best to use that?

Comment: Certainly it is your best reference.